# Text won't stay in parent on site, even though being proven to work on multiple platforms

Tags: html, css

So, I am making this little site (that is still in development) for a friend's birthday. I have tested this exact code on JSFiddle, Codepen, and even the Tryit Now Editor. It worked on all of them. I also tested the two elements individually on site, they both worked fine. But when I combine them, they work on all other platforms but the site itself. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0nRQ.gif), the text does not stay in it's parent. But as you should see in the JSFiddle, it works perfectly fine! What should I do?
(Edit) I found that the embedded version of JSFiddle is also having trouble, but only with the tab names.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script');

body {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html,
body,
#cover {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

#cover {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #444444;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Marck Script;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

html:hover #cover {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#cover-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  max-height: 250px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  max-height: 170px;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div id="cover-text">
   Happy Birthday Adam~!
   <br>
   To Continue Hover Over This!
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Put</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Stuff</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Here</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Pls</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. 
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. 
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. 
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check the way you include the css file/files? The problem is somewhere around CSS, try including it inline.

UPD: The issue is due to normalize.css

```
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It's quite a good practice to use it, but Normalize gives default display:block to sections, you can either remove this feature from normalize.css itself at line 38, or apply !important to the display attribute of the sections while checked and not checked (to both states) in your .css

Or simply switch the places of the css files in your `<head>`, the last one takes the priority if I am not mistaken :)

Comment: I checked and I didn't find anything of my knowledge wrong with it. Pretty darn stuck here.

Comment: It just looks like something makes default state of all the tabs - checked, judjung from the gif, or the display:none doesn't work well (try adding !important to both states of visibility). Can there be any interference from side css? Can u share the link to the "live" problematic version?

Comment: Updating my answer in a moment, found the problem ;)